# How to set gridviews columns as a row of excel file using Spout PHP library

Tags: php, excel, gridview, yii, export-to-excel

I have an 8 linearly related tables. Then a final table is consist ~60 columns and ~24000 rows and I need to export all data into excel file(XLSX format). I decided to use Spout PHP library to export and import files instead of PHPexcel library, because exported data is too big. I configured my project as it is described in [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html;) to work with this library. Also I added this code into a view file.

```
$multipleRows = [
    'columns' => ['id', 
    'sub_id', 
    'address_id', 
    'abc', 
    'bca', 
    'cab', 
    'bac',
    ... //and so on
    ]
];

$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
$writer -> openToFile('c:/www/localhost/project/web/uploads/test.xlsx');
$writer -> addRows($multipleRows);
$writer -> close();
```

But when I am trying to export XLSX file, I got column headers in the first row of Output file. 
What should I do to get an exported file looks like a gridview?

Comment: What result did you expect? Each subarray of `$multipleRows` will become a row in the XLSX file so it makes sense that the headers end up in the first row. What's the gridview format you're talking about?